# Visual Studio 2019 Community Edition method references not displayed in Editor

Tags: c#, visual-studio, reference, visual-studio-2019, method-reference

[image]There is no option of references above the method, property, or any declaration in Visual Studio 2019 Community Edition.

If this option available in Visual Studio 2019 Community Edition then please let me know.

I also attached an image for reference. Thanks in advance. Happy Coding.

Comment: Do you mean CodeLense? References like on [this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jpSiE.png)? That's only shown for methods, not for namespaces or types afaik.

Comment: What is "CodeLense"?

Comment: Google for it. It's a feature of Visual Studio, which I guess (not sure) you are asking about.

Comment: Yes, That is the option I am talking about.

Comment: Then check answers in duplicate and see if they answers your question.

Comment: @Sinatr How can I accept your comment as an answer.

Comment: You don't accept comment as answer. Someone has to post the answer first, but I hope duplicate helped you, then you just have to accept it. There should be a prompt to close your question as duplicate.